# Bottom border on button disappears on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, the bottom border on my button disappears on hover, and I have no idea why. It works perfectly locally, but when I check my site live it disappears.

Here is my Codepen https://codepen.io/ecanada138/pen/ExXRXoW, which is the exact code on my repo.

Here is the site https://8thvisionmedia.netlify.app/, where you can see the problem but it does not show up on CodePen or locally

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: cocogoose-regular;
  src: url('../fonts/Cocogoose-Classic-Medium-trial.ttf');
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.navbar-nav a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 20px;
}

.vimeo-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 9/16*100 = 56.25 */
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77vh;
  /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 16/9*100 = 177.77 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* z-index: -1; */
}

.phone-nav {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1.0)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.desktop-nav-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* .nav-link-desktop::after{
  content: '  |';
} */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .phone-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}

.home-container {
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.home-row {
  padding: 0 10rem 0 10rem;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.home-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.home-col {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.row-copyright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.vision-media-logo {
  width: 3rem;
}

a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1399px) {
  .home-row {
    padding: 0 20rem 0 20rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
  .home-row {
    padding: 0 35rem 0 35rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2200px) {
  .home-row {
    padding: 0 50rem 0 50rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .home-row {
    padding: 0 3rem 0 3rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .home-row {
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
    margin-top: -8rem;
  }
  .home-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .vision-media-logo {
    width: 2rem;
  }
  .col-logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .row-copyright {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    bottom: 0rem;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}


/* .myIcon {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.myIcon:hover .hide {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.myIcon {
  z-index: 1000;
}
*/

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .vimeo-wrapper {
    background-image: url('../images/home-screen-bg.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .vimeo-wrapper iframe {
    display: none;
  }
  .phone-container {
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 515px) {
  .fa-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.75rem;
    padding-left: 0.75rem;
  }
  .desktop-nav-container {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.col-copyright {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav a {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

.create-button {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  font-family: 'cocogoose-regular';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.create-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.create-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  /* color: rgb(255, 255, 255); */
  /* outline: 0; */
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); */
  /* font-family: 'cocogoose-regular'; */
  /* letter-spacing: 2px; */
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* padding: 1rem 2rem; */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5826f42d14.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS SHEETS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
  <title>8th Vision Media | Real Estate Video and Photo Production</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./images/8-vision-logo-favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <!--------------------------------------- NAV BAR --------------------------------------------------->

  <div class="phone-container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xxxxxxl phone-nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-end" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
            <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                      </li> -->

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="./gallery.html">Video Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="./core-values.html">Core Values </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Get In Touch</a>
            </li>


            <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./our-people.html">Our People</a>
                        </li> -->
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/8thvisionmedia/">Our Work</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg desktop-nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div
            class="collapse navbar-collapse desktop-nav-container"
            id="navbarNavAltMarkup"
          >
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a
                class="nav-link nav-link-desktop"
                aria-current="page"
                href="./contact.html"
                >Get In Touch</a
              >
              <a class="nav-link nav-link-desktop" href="./core-values.html"
                >Core Values
              </a>
              <a class="nav-link nav-link-desktop" href="./gallery.html">Video Gallery</a
              >
              <a
                style="border-right: none; text-decoration: none"
                target="_blank"
                href="https://www.instagram.com/8thvisionmedia/"
                >Our Work</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="vimeo-wrapper">
        <iframe
          src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/570788340?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0"
          frameborder="0"
          webkitallowfullscreen
          mozallowfullscreen
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        <div>
          <div class="container-fluid home-container">
            <div class="row home-row">
              <div class="col home-col">
                <!-- <p class="home-text">
                           We create powerful visual content for brands that help drive
                           sales, growth and engagement.
                           </p> -->
                <button
                  onClick="window.open('https://www.8thvisionmedia.com/contact');"
                  class="create-button"
                >
                  <a
                    href="./contact.html
                           "
                    >CREATE WITH US
                  </a>
              </button>



        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="row fa-row text-center">
                     <div class="col fa-col">
                       <span>
                         <a
                           href="https://www.instagram.com/8thvisionmedia/"
                           target="_blank"
                           ><i class="myIcon fab fa-instagram fa-2x"
                             ><p class="hide">What We Do</p></i
                           ></a
                         ></span
                       ><span
                         ><a href="mailto:create@8thvisionmedia.com"
                           ><i class="myIcon far fa-envelope fa-2x"
                             ><p class="hide">Take Your Next Step</p></i
                           ></a
                         >
                       </span>
                     </div>
                     </div> -->
      <div class="row row-logo">
        <div class="col col-logo">
          <img class="vision-media-logo" src="./images/8th-vision-logo.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-copyright">
        <div class="col col-copyright">
          <a>&copy; 2021 8th Vision Media</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see the issue you've described on your live site. Have you tried clearing your cache or forcing a hard refresh so that your browser reloads all site contents?

Comment: It seems to be a browser specific problem. I can see the issue on Chrome and Brave, but it was working flawless on firefox. Try adding one or more of these css styling into the hover class. `backface-visibility: hidden;`,
  `transform: translateZ(0);` and
  `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`

Answer (score 0):

remove  transform: scale(1.1);
it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine on firefox. But I saw the issue on edge. and solved it by adding padding to `.home-col` class.

add the following and it should work fine:

```css
.home-col {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thank you I tried this, but now for some reason when you zoom into the button the text within the button drops very slighty

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly the reason, but changing "scale" value will solve the problem :

```
transform: scale(1.2); for example
```

Comment: thank you I tried this, but now for some reason when you zoom into the button the text within the button drops very slighty